# jQuery Form Plugin reset()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

very simple, how do I make it so it submits then resets my form? I know next to nothing about ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery - this will reset all text fields (text and passwords). If you need to reset other fields (checkboxes...) you will need to clear those also:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
       // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            $('#myForm').find("input[type=text] input[type=password], textarea").val("");
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('myForm').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

or

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```

or

```
$('#myForm').trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML DOM Form reset() function:

### Usage

---

```
...
// Selects the first (index 0) #myForm element and calls the reset method
// (the reset method is available to any HTML DOM form element)
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
...
```

### Links

---

[w3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html)

[w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

Answer (score 0):

After your submit or success of your ajax call add something like:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
    //your ajax call
    $("#forum")[0].reset();// or document.getElementById("forum").reset();
}
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(...){
        $("#forum")[0].reset();// or document.getElementById("forum").reset();
    }
});
```